# Repeated replace calls lead to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, regex, performance

I am mass-processing very large files. I am calling the following method on each URI in each line:

```
public String shortenUri(String uri) {
    uri = uri
            .replace("http://www.lemon-model.net/lemon#", "lemon:")
            .replace("http://babelnet.org/rdf/", "bn:")
            .replace("http://purl.org/dc/", "dc:")
            .replace("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", "rdf:");
    return uri;
}
```

Strangely, this leads to the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BnM.optimize(Pattern.java:5411)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1711)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1054)
at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2239)
at XYZ.shortenUri(XYZ.java:217)
```

I did increase `Xms`and `Xmx` but it did not help. Strangely, I could also not observe an increased memory usage when monitoring the process. Any suggestions on increasing the performance and memory consumption here?

Comment: What's the original value of `uri` you're testing with?

Comment: Just a longer URI such as `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#XMLLiteral`

Comment: Could this just be an issue of too many incoming threads on your container?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? I am using this in a single-threaded environment.

Comment: How often is `shortenUri` called? Is it its full code, or are there more replacements?

Comment: Well, you may join these 4 replace operations into 1: `return uri.replaceAll("http://(?:purl\\.org/(dc)/|(b)abel(n)et\\.org/rdf/|www\\.(?:lemon-model\\.net/(lemon)|w3\\.org/1999/02/22-(rdf)-syntax-ns)#)", "$1$2$3$4$5:");`. The `replace` is based on regex anyway, why not use the regex directly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's pretty smart, but not guaranteed to work. IIRC on Android, you get the String "null" instead of the empty string for an unmatched group.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this happens with file IO, since there should be plenty of time for the GC to work. Unless you're buffering a large amount of lines, and then batching them to that method.

Comment: Since each `replace` creates and returns new string of similar size to *original one* on which it was invoked, if you have many `replace` calls each one will create its own big string. My wild guest is that if you are calling this method quite often your memory may be filled with those temporary strings faster than GC will clear them. If my guess is close to the true, consider using something like https://pastebin.com/mLZn3WSG to avoid having many `replace` calls.

Comment: Or this: https://pastebin.com/0ipq06GE

Answer (score 0):

A quote from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom):

> **Excessive GC Time and OutOfMemoryError**
>
> The parallel collector will throw an OutOfMemoryError if too much time is being spent in garbage collection: if more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered, an OutOfMemoryError will be thrown. This feature is designed to prevent applications from running for an extended period of time while making little or no progress because the heap is too small. If necessary, this feature can be disabled by adding the option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command line.

1. The first thing you could try is to increase the heap size even more, for example, fot a few GB with `-Xmx4G`.
2. Another option might be to prevent the creation of too many objects by not using the `replace` method. Instead you could create the `Pattern` and `Matcher` objects as needed (see below).
3. The third option I see is to disable this feature altogether with `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

   ```
   private static final Pattern PURL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("http://purl.org/dc/");
   // other patterns

   public static String shortenUri(String uri) {
       // other matchers
       Matcher matcher = PURL_PATTERN.matcher(uri);
       return matcher.replaceAll("dc:");
   }
   ```